# How can I use a stored procedure as a subquery in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: xml, plsql

I'm new to PL SQL and wonder if the following is possible

I need to generate an xml based on multiple queries from multiple tables. I know I can do the following:

```
with storage_info as (
    select storage_name as "storage_name"
           , id as "storage_id" 
    from storage 
    where             
    .....
    ),
    location_info as (
    select location_name as "location_name", id as "location_id" from location         
    where .....
    )
select xmlserialize(document
    xmlelement("storage",
    xmlelement("storageName", "storage_name"),                                     
    xmlelement("storageId", "storage_id"),                          
    xmlelement("location",
    (select xmlagg(
    xmlelement("locationId", "location_id"),                                     
    xmlelement("locationName", "location_name")                                               
    ) from location_info
    )
    )) from storage_info;
```

This makes it very easy to separate the query from the xml generation. However, I would like to have one procedure for xml generation and separate ones for the queries, as this makes the xml generation procedure smaller and easier to maintain, while also being able to reuse the queries procedures. But if I return a cursor from the stored procedure I have to:

1. the variables in the xml generation procedure
2. fetch the data from the variables into the stored procedure

This seems tedious as the approach above doesn't need any of that. Is there any way around this if I want to use stored procedures for the queries? Should I use views for the queries instead?

**EDIT:**
I found something similar to what I wanted achieve but not quite.
I can declare a cursor like this:

```
declare
 cursor store_info
 is
     select store_id, store_name 
     from store 
     where store_id = 26964;
 begin
     for rec in store_info
     loop
         dbms_output.put_line(rec.store_id || rec.store_name);
     end loop;
 end;
```

This way I can query the data directly without having to put the values into any variables, but I can't find a way to write the procedures like this and then call it from the xml generation procedure.

Comment: Sounds like views are what you need.

Comment: I realized right after writing that view is probably not gonna be the right way to go because I want to send inputs for the where clauses of the queries, not do an additional where filtering on the view in the xml generation.

Comment: How are you going to be calling the xml generation procedure? Is this an OLTP-type thing (i.e. a one-off call somewhere along the point of processing a single thing (e.g. adding a stock item), or is a batch-type thing where you're taking data from one cursor and looping over it to do the xml generation a row at a time?

Comment: Also, is it purely for code modularity that you want to split the queries off from the xml generation query? If so, you can do that but you pay a price with performance.  You could bulk collect the results into a collection, and then use the collection in your query. Personally, I'd stick with repeating the queries in a separate procedure if that's really what you need to do. Yes it means you have to update the query in multiple places (so comment your code!) but it means your xml generation logic can run directly against the tables without having to do context switching etc etc